# Trying to save file in documents folder doesn't work using Buffered Writer

Tags: java

I'm trying to save user input into a .txt file which is supposed to be stored in a folder called 'ht' in documents folder but it doesn't.
Note: The file gets saved when I save directly to the documents folder.

Heres my code:

```
public void saveUserData() throws IOException {
//        Path path = Paths.get(filename);
        Path path = Paths.get(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().getPath()+"\\"+"ht"+"\\"+filename);
        BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path);
        try {
            Iterator<FormInput> iter = dataItems.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FormInput item = iter.next();
                bw.write(String.format("%s\t%s",
                        item.getUserName(),
                        item.getPassword()));
                bw.newLine();
            }
        } finally {
            if (bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do mean when you say it doesn't work? Does it throw an exception? Does it save the file somewhere else? Instead of using things like `a.getB().dogetC().doD()`, split that up into individual statements and examine the results of each individual operation.

Comment: does not save the file at all, I also replaced the path declaration above with Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "ht", fileName) and still got nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid concatenating paths manually. It's error-prone, and you might mess up complexities arising from different operating-systems.

You're already using Java's `Path` api, which has a convenience method that takes varargs: `Paths.get(String first, String... more)`. So, change it to something like: `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "ht", fileName)`

Now, `FileSystemView` is `Swing` api that attempts to launch a GUI and gets stuck. I've replaced it with `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

-- Update --

If the directory doesn't exist already:

```java
    Path dir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "ht");
    if (!Files.exists(dir)) {
      Files.createDirectories(dir);
    }
```

Comment: the folder does not still get created but it works if I omit ht

Comment: If the directory doesn't exist, you would have to create it first. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hurray It Worked!! just had to add ```Path path = Paths.get(dir+"\\"+filename);``` to save the file in that folder.Thanks a lot.